# Steam issues after installing Mesa Intel Iris Xe PPA on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, steam, mesa

I recently installed Mesa Intel Iris Xe graphics drivers using [this guide](https://itsfoss.com/install-mesa-ubuntu).  Now, Steam refuses to load at all. It simply gets to verification completed, pauses, and then stops when run from the terminal. I installed both of the drivers listed here.

terminal output:

```
[2022-04-28 13:15:27] Startup - updater built 
Mar 14 2022 19:48:46 Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2022-04-28 13:15:27] Failed to load cached hosts file (File 'update_hosts_cached.vdf' not found), using defaults
[2022-04-28 13:15:27] Using the following download hosts for Public, Realm steamglobal 
[2022-04-28 13:15:27] 1. http://media.steampowered.com, /client/, Realm 'steamglobal', weight was 1, source = 'baked in'
[2022-04-28 13:15:27] Checking for update on startup
[2022-04-28 13:15:27] Checking for available updates...
[2022-04-28 13:15:27] Downloading manifest: http://media.steampowered.com/client/steam_client_ubuntu12
[2022-04-28 13:15:28] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1647446817, installed version 1647446817, existing pending version 0
[2022-04-28 13:15:28] Nothing to do 
[2022-04-28 13:15:28] Verifying installation...
[2022-04-28 13:15:28] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2022-04-28 13:15:28] Verification complete
```

running ppa purge the frist time returns

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
```

```
Updating packages lists
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F63F0F2B90935439
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

running:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove kisak/kisak-mesa
```

returns nothing

And

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

Returns

```
PLEASE READ: don't email me to report bugs, unless you are sure it's a packaging bug. Not only is email not a good tool for tracking bugs, it also excludes anybody else from tracking or working on the issue. Please read the section "Debugging and reporting problems" below.

Also, please don't ask me to include non-free drivers, I won't do it.

Patches and suggestions are welcomed.

=============

All Ubuntu architectures are supported.

Supported Ubuntu versions:
- 20.04 (focal) <- obsolete
- 21.10 (impish) <- obsolete
- 22.04 (jammy) <- supported
- 22.10 (kinetic) <- supported

For forum support see: http://goo.gl/qoUpWK

=== Introduction ===
This PPA provides updated free graphics drivers (from mesa). Updates packages provide:
 * all driver packages are automagically built every day, when there are upstream changes
 * Vulkan 1.3+ and OpenGL 4.6+ : http://mesamatrix.net
 * gallium-nine support. Read the specific section below
 * VDPAU and VAAPI Gallium3D accelerated video drivers (see below)
 * packages built against latest stable LLVM
 * mesa packages built with gcc LTO for smaller binary size (~10-15%) and improved performance

As an added bonus I may include some updated open source games (backported from Debian or newer Ubuntu).

=== Basic usage ===
See "Adding this PPA to your system" later on, or just do:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
and update your Ubuntu with the package here.

=== Using gallium-nine ===
Gallium-nine lets you run DirectX 9 games in a faster way, avoiding the inefficient translation of D3D9 calls to OpenGL. For more info see https://wiki.ixit.cz/d3d9
You need:
 * enable this PPA (see previous paragraph)
 * then follow the instructions to install wine from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~commendsarnex/+archive/ubuntu/winedri3

=== Using alternative drivers - Here be dragons ===
* zink - OpenGL emulated on a Vulkan driver:
  Set MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=zink
* zink + lavapipe - OpenGL emulated on a software Vulkan driver:
  Set VK_ICD_FILENAMES=/usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/lvp_icd.x86_64.json MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=zink
* llvmpipe OpenGL software render:
  Set MESA_LOADER_DRIVER_OVERRIDE=llvmpipe
* Other options here: https://www.mesa3d.org/envvars.html

=== Using accelerated video ===
Supported VDPAU drivers: r300, r600, radeonsi, nouveau
Supported VAAPI drivers: r600, radeonsi

* First you need to install mesa-vdpau-drivers package:
sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers

* Then to test the VDPAU driver with mpv use:
$ mpv --hwdec=vdpau yourvideofile

=== Upgrading to a newer Ubuntu ===
It is *strongly* suggested to remove all packages from this PPA before updating to a newer Ubuntu release. See the section "Revert to original drivers" later on.
Then, after the upgrade, you can add again this PPA.

=== Debugging and reporting problems ===
If you have some problem with the drivers try running the application from the command line and see if there are graphics related warnings. Also type dmesg to see if there are other related information here.

If you get crashes install the relevant -dbg pacakges (libgl1-mesa-dri-dbg or libgl1-mesa-dri-experimental-dbg for 3D drivers and xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg , xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-dbg or xserver-xorg-video-radeon-dbg for X drivers) and reproduce the crash with gdb. Example:
$ gdb glxgears
[...make your application crash and then get a backtrace with:]
(gdb) bt

If X.org crashes look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log (or /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old when a new X session is started after the crash).

With the gathered information try searching at https://bugs.freedesktop.org/query.cgi (also try with google) if someone already reported a similar bug. If not you may want to report a new bug:
for 3D drivers bugs: https://www.mesa3d.org/bugs.html
for X / 2D driver bugs: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=xorg

=== Revert to original drivers ===
To revert to standard Ubuntu drivers type the following in a prompt shell:
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

=== Donations ===
Some people asked me if I can accept donations to support this work. I don't, but if you have some spare money I would be happy if you could do a donation to a charity of your choice (for the poors, animals, whatever else you may think it might need it). Then feel free to send me a note about it!
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel removing it.
```

I pressed [ENTER]:

however, running:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
```

Returns

```
Updating packages lists
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F63F0F2B90935439
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
```

Comment: yes i did however it doesn't seam to have worked i also will file a bug report so this issue can get fixed for others too also sorry about the double post but i posted the 1st one at 1am and then realized that many people probably wouldn't see it

Comment: i tried already but when running the command listed on the page it outputs Updating packages lists
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F63F0F2B90935439
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kisak/kisak-mesa/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason

Comment: after running sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers the terminal i just sitting there no output i am unsure weather its doing anything is this normal?

Comment: while ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers removed just fine kisak/kisak-mesa now says Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: kisak kisak-mesa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: kisak kisak-mesa when useing ppa purge and apt-get --remove does nothing

Comment: yea give me a second

Comment: okay updated it

Comment: Removing the PPAs does NOT remove whatever was installed from them. You may want to install `ppa-purge` and then run it against both. In the future avoid such experiments. Intel Graphics run with open-source drivers, automatically installed, and they do work fine with Steam.

Comment: as shown above ppa purge does not work

Comment: @Nmath any ideas?

Comment: You need to remove not only the PPA but you also have to remove whatever packages you installed.  It's also possible that you have other issues with package management (check to make sure `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` complete successfully without errors). Some actions are just more difficult to undo than they were to begin-- in some cases it may be more prudent to reinstall the OS if you keep encountering problems

Comment: how about fixing the GPG signature error?

Comment: You can try that but it doesn't make sense to me when you need to remove the PPA. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/15272. Are you sure you don't have other problematic packages or PPAs?  PPAs can break your system: See [Are PPAs safe](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629)

Comment: After doing some work i found that the PPAs Signature was invaild thairfore ubuntu wouldnt let me remove it so after fixing that steam still refused to work citing missing dependencies specifically libc6 which ubuntu refuses to let me reinstall as it was out of date and coreupted and it told me to run sudo apt-get --fix-broken install to fix it when i did the computer shut down and now refuses to boot other than recovery mode so i am just going to reinstall ubuntu